# how to collect data from user with the facebook messenger bot api in node js

Tags: chat, artificial-intelligence, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am building a messenger bot in node. I want it to collect user input data and have a conversation or ask questions, but the code I have doesn't work. the part that does not work is it only continues to the next else if block if i type the same code. and second the array is not capturing the text after the first if statement. Is there a better way to do it? Could someone provide code?

My code is below. what i want is like in this iimage:

[image: screenshot]

```
var currentbot = 0;
var awnswers = [];
app.post('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  var events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
      var text = event.message.text;
      if (text == "hi") {
        start(event.message.text, event.sender.id);
      }
    }
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
var awnswers = [];

function start(text, id) {
  if (count == 0) {
    sendTextMessage('hello lets order!', id);
    arr.push(text);
    console.log(awnswers);
    count = 1;
  } else if (count == 1) {
    sendTextMessage('what size do you want?', id);
    arr.push(text);
    console.log(awnswers);
    count = 2;
  } else if (count == 2) {
    sendTextMessage('its on its way!', id);
    arr.push(text);
    console.log(awnswers);
    count = 0;
  }
}

function sendTextMessage(messageText, recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: messageText
    }
  };
  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {
      access_token: process.env.access_token
    },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;
      console.log("Successfully sent generic message with id %s to recipient %s", messageId, recipientId);
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message.");
      console.error(response);
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: "the code I have doesn't work" -- What exactly "doesn't work"? Is there an error message (and a line number)? StackOverflow is not a code-writing or debugging service. Please provide a more succinct problem.

Comment: @LambdaNinja the part that does not work is it only continues to the next else if block if i type the same code. and second the array is not capturing the text after the first if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues I think I see are:

1. Start() is only called when text == hi
2. Count is not defined
3. You're pushing to the array 'arr' not, awnswers

You can fix these by:

1. Calling start() on every message
2. Defining count like var count = 0; at the top of your file, next to var currentbot
3. awnswers.push(text);